# Why does 'styles' alone have a square bracket inside @Component decorator?

Tags: angular

Can I know why is it that 'styles' alone have a square bracket inside @Component decorator? I know that [] are used for property binding and arrays.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-component-overview',
  template: '<h1>Hello World!</h1>',
  styles: ['h1 { font-weight: normal; }']
})
```

Comment: Because it does support array and it can support multiple numbers of styles, refer https://angular.io/guide/component-styles

Comment: BTW, the `styleUrls` property also accepts an array with multiple files. Eg. `styleUrls: [ './app.component.css', './header.css', './footer.css', ...]`

Comment: And for the record, the `animations` property also support an array that accepts multiple animation triggers.

Comment: Thank you for bringing clarity. Is there an advantage that the use of array gives to animations, styles and styleUrls?  'template' property works fine even without array. Why wouldn't style: ` body {background-color: powderblue;}
                                  h1   {color: blue;}
                                  p    {color: red;} `  be good enough?